# Reservas Aulas con distintas franjas horarias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

el servidor tiene que ser capaz de reservar un aula 30 min, 1 hora o 1 hora y media.

La base de datos:

describe usuarios;

```
'id','int(11)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'username','varchar(64)','NO','',NULL,''
'email','varchar(64)','NO','',NULL,''
```

describe clases;

```
'id','int(11)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'tipo','varchar(64)','NO','',NULL,''
```

describe reservas;

```
'id','int(11)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'fecha','date','NO','',NULL,''
'horaInicio','time','NO','',NULL,''
'horaFin','time','NO','',NULL,''
'clases_id_id','int(11)','NO','MUL',NULL,''
'usuarios_id_id','int(11)','NO','MUL',NULL,''
```

Mi problema, los rangos para las consultas, ya que sé hacerlo si fuese de hora en hora porque haría:

```
select * from reservas where clases_id_id=1 and fecha = "2016-05-17" and horaInicio >= "19:00" and horaFin <= "20:00";
```

Y el resultado:

```
'4','2016-05-17','19:00:00','20:00:00','1','1'
```

Las reservas que ya hay hechas:

```
select * from reservas;

'1','2016-05-17','09:30:00','11:00:00','1','1'
'2','2016-05-17','12:00:00','13:30:00','1','1'
'3','2016-05-17','12:00:00','12:30:00','1','1'
'4','2016-05-17','19:00:00','20:00:00','1','1'
```

Ahora si quiero ver la siguiente hora, compruebo que hay hueco disponible:

```
select * from reservas where clases_id_id=1 and fecha = "2016-05-17" and horaInicio >= "20:00" and horaFin <= "21:00";
```

Dicha consulta no arroja resultado.

Pero si ahora quiero reservar de media hora en media hora, cómo podría hacerlo y luego hacer un php para generar un JSON con el contenido de la reserva, ya que si hago:

```
select * from reservas where clases_id_id=1 and fecha = "2016-05-17" and horaInicio >= "09:30" and horaFin <= "10:00";
```

Me sale como libre, vamos que no arroja ningún resultado y es por la condición del final, ya que las 11 no es menor o igual que las 10:00.

¿A alguien se le ocurre como solucionar este problema?

Gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

no se si entendi bien, tu ingresas las dos horas para buscar si esta reservado en esos 30 mins. puedes cambiar al rango al que tu necesites.

```
select * 
from reservas 
where clases_id_id=1 
and fecha = "2016-05-17" 
AND horaInicio BETWEEN "09:30" AND "10:00"
OR horaFin BETWEEN "09:30" AND "10:00"
```

espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Yo simplemente cambiaría los comparadores, usando la siguiente lógica:

```
select * from reservas where clases_id_id=1 and fecha = "2016-05-17" and horaInicio <= "09:30" and horaFin >= "10:00";
```

De esta forma voy a obtener todas las reservas que fueron iniciadas hasta las 9:30 y que terminan a partir de las 10:00.

Pero, ¿qué pasa si una reserva inicia a las 9:45 y termina a las 10:15 y queremos conocer si la sala está ocupada entre las 9:30 y las 10:00?

Una solución rápida (no probada) sería agregar un OR de dos condiciones que encuentre las reservas que inician antes y terminan después de la hora inicial y lo mismo para la hora final:

```
select * from reservas where clases_id_id=1 and fecha = "2016-05-17" and (horaInicio <= "09:30" and horaFin >= "09:30" or horaInicio <= "10:00" and horaFin >= "10:00" or horaInicio > "09:30" and horaFin < "10:00") ;
```

Agregué una tercera condición al OR, para casos en los que se desee buscar en rangos más grandes, por ejemplo entre las 09:00 y las 11:00.

De esta forma debería poder obtener, por ejemplo (para nuestro caso del intevalo entra las 9:30 y las 10:00):

- Una reserva que exista entre las 9:10 y 9:40
- Una reserva entre las 9:30 y 10:00
- Una reserva entre las 9:45 y 10:15
- Una reserva entre las 9:35 y las 9:50 (aunque no se aceptan reservas de menos de 30 min en el escenario planteado)

Comment: No habría casos como las 9:45-10:15, porque puedo poner que abran las clases a las 9 y las cierren a las 21. El problema es que si hay una reserva de '19:00:00','20:00:00' y hago la búsqueda de 18:30 a 19:30 no me arroja ningún resultado.:(

Comment: Hice una emulación rápida de tu situación en Postgres y me funciona perfectamente: `select * from aulas where fecha = '2016-05-17' and (horainicio <= '18:30' and horafin >= '18:30' or horainicio <= '19:30' and horafin >= '19:30' or horainicio > '18:30' and horafin < '19:30');`

Comment: Hola, con esta sentencia funciona lo de antes, pero en el caso de tener un hueco entre las 11 y las 13:30 y hacer la query: select * from reservas where fecha = '2016-05-17' and (horainicio <= '11:00' and horafin >= '11:00' or horainicio <= '13:30' and horafin >= '13:30' or horainicio > '11:00' and horafin < '13:30'); me arroja como resultado: ''1','2016-05-17','09:30:00','11:00:00','1','1' ||
'3','2016-05-17','13:30:00','14:30:00','1','1' ||
   en lugar de mostrarme el hueco libre. Gracias por estar intentando ayudarme, es de agradecer

Comment: Bueno, ahi claramente se ve el hueco entre las 11 y las 13:30, ya el resto depende de la lógica de tu software y de tu escenario..

Comment: El problema es que tengo que sacar los huecos disponibles en función del tiempo que yo quiera reservar el aula. Por lo tanto si la consulta no me muestra el hueco como libre, no se me ocurre el implementarlo vía software :(

Comment: Estoy viendo tu forma de hacerlo a ver si puedo hacer algo por software pero es que si hay un hueco de 9:00 a 9:30 y después a partir de las 9:30 está ocupada, al hacer la consulta de 9:00 a 9:30 me muestra la reserva ocupada de las 9:30 a 11:00. La verdad es que este tema me tiene superado, no sé como implementarlo.

Comment: Simplemente es jugar con los operadores de comparación, reemplaza > por >= o viceversa, realmente ya depende de tu implementación, no es algo complicado.

Comment: Ok, lo miraré más detalladamente.